# jQuery: Function is called twice. Propagation? Why does this happen?

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

Please take a look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K9NjY/

I've spend 3-4 hours on this code and I've narrowed it down to the shortest version and now I'm stuck.

Problem:
1. Click 'divOne'
2. Click switch DivNames
3. Click 'divTwo'

***Why is divOne still being alerted? How do I stop this? *** Logic would tell me that when we click `divTwo` we should only get one alert that says 'divTwo'

Notice that `doSomething()` has a function that's triggered by a `click` inside it. This cannot change i.e. `$("." + divName).click(function(){...});`  must remain inside `doSomething()`

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the event listeners using `off` and add again, switching the class names won't unbind existing event listeners -

```
function doSomething(divName){

    $(".action").off().addClass(divName).html(divName).click(function(){
        alert(divName);
    });
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/johnbk/Y3GSr/)

Answer (score 4):

Events are bound to elements not to their classNames, whenever the function is called, you are attaching a click handler to the matched element. That's why you see several handlers being called. You can either use event delegation by using the passed parameter or use the `off` method for removing the handlers.

edit: Usually when you are attaching several handlers to an element, you are doing something wrong. Attaching event handlers in other handlers is a recipe for pain. The logic should be moved into the handler's body instead.

This is what I'd probably do in this case:

```
var $e = $(".action").on('click', function() {
     var action = $(this).data('action');
     // Do something based on the element's current `action` datum
     if (action === 'whatever') {
       // ...
     } else {
       // ...
     }
});

function doSomething(divName) {
    $e.html(divName).data('action', divName);
}
```

Here the `action` datum can be used in the handler's logic.

Comment: How would I use the `off` method in this scenario pls?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Google Chrome, the easiest way to find things like this out is by using the component view. You can see there, that before clicking the Switch div name, the first div looks like this:

```
<div class="action divOne">divOne</div>
```

after clicking it, it looks like this

```
<div class="action divOne divTwo">divTwo</div>
```

meaning you just added divTwo, but never removed divOne. You're also calling a function that was in turn called at the script start.

Where you're saying:

```
doSomething("divOne");//First call on Dom Ready
```

It already calls that function. That is why you get both divOne and divTwo as a response after switching.

This updated one will function as you'd expect.
http://jsfiddle.net/K9NjY/2/

Comment: @Johnbabu Koppolu has a better solution if you wish to remain with your current layout.